Indicator does not get updated in the bar replay mode
I have the following indicator, it is a simple FVG, I noticed that when I am using bar replay my indicator does not get updated.
For example, if a FVG has to be stop or updated it wont happen. If I move the bar replay and restart again, things get updated but it wont keep updating itself.
I am wondering how can I fix it?
//@version=5
indicator("FVG", shorttitle="FVG", overlay = true, max_boxes_count = 500)

color_not_used = input.color(color.new(#d1d4dc,65), "Not Used")

lastBarsFilterInput = input.int(1000, "Bars Count:")

show_letter = input.bool(false, "Show U or D")

var box boxUp = na
var BoxesInformationThatAreUSed = array.new_box(0)
var AllBoxes = box.all

[high_0,low_0,high_1,high_2,low_1,low_2,open_0,close_0,close_1,time_0,time_2,bar_index_0,open_1,open_2,close_2] = request.security(ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid),timeframe.period,[high,low,high[1],high[2],low[1],low[2],open,close,close[1],time[0],time[2],bar_index,open[1],open[2],close[2]],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
isAllowed = (last_bar_index - bar_index < lastBarsFilterInput)

candle_2_open = open_2
candle_2_close = close_2
candle_2_high = high_2
candle_2_low = low_2

candle_1_open = open_1
candle_1_close = close_1
candle_1_high = high_1
candle_1_low = low_1

candle_0_open = open_0
candle_0_close = close_0
candle_0_high = high_0
candle_0_low = low_0


fvg = candle_2_high<candle_0_low 
diff = candle_2_high-candle_0_low 
if isAllowed 
    
    if fvg
        boxUp := box.new(bottom=candle_2_high, left=time_2, top=candle_0_low, right=time_0, bgcolor=color_not_used, extend = extend.right,xloc=xloc.bar_time, border_color=color_not_used,text = show_letter?"D":"",text_valign = text.align_bottom,text_size = size.tiny)
        AllBoxes := box.all
    else

        if array.size(AllBoxes) > 0  
            for i = 0 to array.size(AllBoxes) - 1
                if (box.get_top(array.get(AllBoxes, i))>candle_0_low  and not array.includes(BoxesInformationThatAreUSed, array.get(AllBoxes, i)))
                    box.set_extend(array.get(AllBoxes, i),extend.none)
                    box.set_right(array.get(AllBoxes, i),right=time_0)

                    array.push(BoxesInformationThatAreUSed, array.get(AllBoxes, i) )
        


